# Why ListView shows nothing when I use .xml form data?

Tags: android

When I construct a spinner, I use this process,
res/layout/main.xml

```
 <Spinner  android:id="@+id/spinner" />

 <resources>
     <string-array name="planets_array">
         <item>Neptune</item> 
        ...
     </string-array>
 </resources>
```

But when construct a ListView data, we use,

```
publicclass mListView extends Activity {
  private static final String[] strs = new String[] {
"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"
   }; ...
```

and When I try to use this listview data form instead, res/layout/main.xml

```
 <ListView  android:id="@+id/lstview" />

 <resources>
     <string-array name="planets_array">
         <item>Neptune</item> 
        ...
     </string-array>
 </resources>
```

I get nothing shown , what's matter?

Comment: shows us  some code where you populate listview, You have this  `<ListView  android:id="@+id/lstview" />`  in values.xml??

Comment: pls see user2247689's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `string-arrays` you can directly declare entries in the layout file.

```
<ListView ... android:entries="@array/planets-array"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. you are right. when I use entries, it can show without any another extra java code. I have asked this question before, but none put out an answer. I want to know what's different between them? spinner and listview.

Comment: yes, no java code is required. Please also accept the answer :)